# Why I'm getting a 502 bad gateway error when installing go packages

Tags: go, go-get

I tried installing the `golang.org/x/oauth2` and `google.golang.org/api/vision/v1` packages by running

```
go get golang.org/x/oauth2
go get google.golang.org/api/vision/v1
```

but I get this error

> go get: google.golang.org/api@v0.63.0 requires
> cloud.google.com/go@v0.99.0: reading
> https://mirrors.aliyun.com/goproxy/cloud.google.com/go/@v/v0.99.0.mod:
> 502 Bad Gateway

Is there an alternative way of installing these packages?
I'm on go version 1.17.5.

Comment: change a proxy?

Comment: This error should be relative to the goproxy you use from https://mirrors.aliyun.com, then try to use other proxy providers such as https://goproxy.io, https://goproxy.cn.

Comment: Changing the proxy worked. I changed the GOPROXY to https://proxy.golang.org. Thanks guys.